# Fetch latest date-time in mysql for every user id

Tags: php, mysql

```
   user_id   payment_end_time 
    1674    2008-01-10 07:51:21
    1675    2008-01-05 17:48:51
    1675    2009-01-20 16:56:04
    1675    2010-01-27 13:16:34
    1676    2008-01-05 20:21:35
    1676    2009-01-07 18:46:41
    1676    2009-12-08 13:59:08
    1677    2008-01-05 20:30:16
    1677    2009-01-03 19:11:03
    1677    2009-10-07 06:24:58
    1678    2008-01-26 06:23:46
    1678    2009-01-18 12:19:58
    1679    2008-01-06 12:11:29
    1679    2009-01-23 08:44:51
    1680    2008-03-28 18:58:20
    1680    2009-12-31 16:39:46
    1681    2008-01-07 07:24:03
    1682    2008-01-07 11:37:43
    1682    2009-01-16 20:26:16
    1682    2010-02-02 09:38:34
```

1.The user_id is not unique because a user can pay more than once. Each payment for a given user inserts a new row.

2.I have to fields in database user_id(not primary key) and payment_end_time.

3.I want  output for every  user_id with payment_end_time(latest date-time for every user i.e Order By DESC).

4.I want this for every user_id just once i.e for user_id (1675     2010-01-27 13:16:34)
(1676   2009-12-08 13:59:08) like this similarly for 1677 and so on..

I have tried this

SELECT  user_id, MAX(payment_end_time) 
FROM  tbl_payment_info
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY payment_end_time DESC
LIMIT 1

I have tried this but it just display me single row .I want every USER_id just once with with latest date-time

Comment: You should show us your effort - "What have you tried?".

Comment: Hint: read about SQL `GROUP BY` and `MAX`

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
SELECT  user_id, MAX(payment_end_time) latest_payment_end_time
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY latest_payment_end_time DESC
```

Comment: sir it is showing 1675 three times. I just want 1675 only once with latest date-time, similarly with 1676.. and so on

Comment: What data type is user_id? INT or something different (possibly VARCHAR(10))? GROUP BY should actually ensure that each unique user_id entry appears only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `payment` ORDER BY payment_end_time DESC) AS `p` GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: This query does exactly what you need. I just imported your data, run the query, and got unique user_id with latest date. Can you explain, what exactly isn't working?